# How can i get TZoffset in T-SQL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016, localdb

I have a following code I want to know on which TZoffset is it? How can I calculate TZoffset? Here the code

```
SELECT DATENAME(day, '1998-01-08 20:20:30.1234567 +2:00');
```

After all, this is what I know:

```
Datepart            Return Value
yyyy                 1998
quarter              1
month                January
dayofyear            08
day                  08
week                 2
weekday              Sunday
hour                 20
minutes              20
seconds              30
milliseconds         123
microseconds         1234567
nanoseconds          123456700
TZoffset          ?....(?).....? help, how do I get it?.
ISOWW                 2
```

Help me on how to find/calculate TZoffset.

Comment: I would have thought the +2:00 should be +02:00. What is the exact SQL statement you are using to get the timezone?

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to get it, according to my code:

```
select datename(day, '1998-01-08 20:20:30.1234567 +2:00')
```

by using running the following code it will provide you with the correct tzoffset, like this:

```
select datename(tzoffset, '1998-01-08 20:20:30.1234567 +2:00')
```

The code returned +2:00 as my tzoffset.